# How to write "End of exam" in the last exam page?

Tags: exam, examdesign

I am using exam class as \documentclass[12pt]{examdesign}.

I am writing an multi-choices question for exam and my name only in the first page, and I wanted the last page (the final) to be End of Exam. However, I can not put the "End of exam" in the last page as my code!

In my exam.sty file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{exam}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\parskip=0pt
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter


\newcommand{\@name}{\ }
\newcommand{\@examend}{\ }

\newcounter{codeforexam}

\newcommand{\name}[1]{\renewcommand{\@hovaten}{\makebox[10cm]{{\bf #1:}\dotfill} }}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\Fullpages}{\setlength{\topmargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pc}
                        \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
                        \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
                        \setlength{\textwidth}{17truecm}
                        \setlength{\textheight}{25truecm}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1cm}
}

\makeatletter
\def\firstpageforexam{
\begin{examtop}

%-----------------------------

\makebox[24cm]{{\bf \@name \textcolor{red}{\small{Name:\dotfill; ID: \dotfill  }}}}\\
\@name

\end{examtop}
}
%%%%%%
```

Comment: Never ever set `\hoffset` or `\voffset`. If you're using A4 paper, declare it and use `geometry` for setting the page parameters.

Comment: Since it looks like you are writing a package, do _not_ use `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`! As far as your question is concerned, maybe you are simply looking for `\AtEndDocument`.

Comment: You could possibly add it to \endquestions.